# Which is ‘more correct’: "It has been a month since you graduated" or "It has been a month since you ʜᴀᴠᴇ graduated"?

Tags: grammaticality, present-perfect, sequence-of-tenses

I am unsure on whether to use or to omit the word *have* in a particular sentence:

1. It **has been** a month since you graduated.
2. It **has been** a month since you **have** graduated.

I believe that it may be ok without it, but at the same time,
it may also be not only just ok to use it but more acceptable
to do so than to omit it.

Shouldn't I keep using present prefect throughout the sentence
instead of mixing different kinds of pasts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When do i use "I" and "I have"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/445317/when-do-i-use-i-and-i-have)

Comment: @livresque - your reference is on point, but that answer is unusable.

Comment: Your question is based on a false premise because neither is innately more correct than the other. What'd be more "correct" would depend on intended meaning, but such is the nuance that there's often overlap. In a nutshell, if you're meaning to refer to some *present effect* of the past action "graduate," you'd be more apt to use the present perfect "have graduated," like if you're saying the sentence as a segue to ask what they're now going to do with their diploma or degree. If not, you wouldn't, like if you're segueing to ask what they've been up to for the past month. So it depends.

Answer (score -1):

> Shouldn't I keep using present prefect throughout the sentence instead of mixing different kinds of pasts?

If the events in each clause happened at the same time, you can use the same tense in each clause. That is not true in this situation: the first clause describes the period from graduation to now ([present perfect](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/present-perfect) is the best choice to describe this), and the second clause describes an event that happened a month ago ([past simple](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/past-simple) is the best choice to describe this). This is what you get:

> It has been a month since you graduated.